# Check if multiple records match a set of values

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there a way to write a single query to check if a set of rows matches a set of values? I have one row per set of values that I need to match and I'd like to know if all rows are matched or not. I could perform this via multiple queries such as:

```
select * from tableName where (value1, value2) = ('someValue1', 'someValue2')
select * from tableName where (value1, value2) = ('someOtherValue1', 'someOtherValue2')
```

...and so on, up to an arbitrary number of queries. How could this sort of thing be re-written as a single query where the query returns ONLY if all values are matched?

Comment: Hmm, but how can `value1` match `someValue1` and also `someOtherValue1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like:

```
select t.* 
from tableName t
join (select 'someValue1' value1, 'someValue2' value2 union all
      select 'someOtherValue1', 'someOtherValue2') v
  on t.value1 = v.value1 and t.value2 = v.value2
where 2=
(select count(distinct concat(v1.value1, v1.value2))
 from (select 'someValue1' value1, 'someValue2' value2 union all
       select 'someOtherValue1', 'someOtherValue2') v1
 join tableName t1
   on t1.value1 = v1.value1 and t1.value2 = v1.value2)
```

If you have a large number of value pairs that you want to check, it may be easier to insert them into a temporary table and use the temporary table in the above query, instead of two separate hard-coded virtual tables.

Comment: Excellent stuff - much appreciated!

Comment: @Mark Bannister, I don't understand the concat usage, and it seems you missed a closing parenthesis after the where. Can you explain this answer?

Comment: @Raffaele: I have updated the answer - I hope it's a little clearer now.

Comment: @MarkBannister, sorry I don't get it :( You use a `count distinct` on a string built from `v join t` instead of `v1 join t1` (which is the `select count` *scope*). I don't get the point of all this code - maybe because I can't understand the original question :) See [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e81da/7)

Comment: @Raffaele: mea culpa - the count distinct concat should have been on results from v1 (corrected now). See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e81da/19 - if run with all four records in `person`, it returns both specified values, but if run without John's record, it returns nothing.

Comment: Ok so the purpose of the OP is  getting the records matching a set of conditions, but only if for each condition in the set exists one and only one record. Isn't it?

Comment: @Raffaele: From the original question: "ONLY if all values are matched" - I interpreted this as meaning "only if for all conditions in the set exists at least one matching record".

Answer (score 2):

What about:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tableName 
WHERE value1 IN ('someValue1', 'someOtherValue1') AND 
      value2 IN ('someValue2', 'someOtherValue2')
```

Comment: I clarified my question a bit more - in that example I am expecting two rows since I have two sets of values that I need to match. I believe the query you suggested would be satisfied by only one row since it uses IN clauses.

Comment: @Josh I didn't quite understand you, can you post an example?

Answer (score 0):

Match if exactly two records found
Select students who got q13 wrong and Q14 right

```
SELECT qa.StudentID FROM questionAnswer qa, Student s 
WHERE qa.StudentID=s.StudentID   AND  
      ((QuestionID=13  AND Pass=0) OR (QuestionID=14 AND Pass=1))
GROUP BY qa.StudentID
HAVING COUNT(*)=2;
```

The Where clause matches any records where q14 is correct and q13 is incorrect
We then group by the StudentID
The having requires there to be two records